# Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

Tried timeout and done() function to solve this problem but it is not working showing Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; error.

Controller

```
var plan_details = require('../../models/plan_details');
module.exports = function () {
return {
    getPlansList: function (request, callback) {
        plan_details.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).exec().then((result) => {
            log.info("Getting All Plan Details");
            callback({ status: 200, success: true, result: result });
        }).catch(err => {
            log.error("Getting error while getting all plans");
            log.error(err);
            callback({ status: 400, success: false, message: "Unable to 
            Process your Request" });
        });
    }
 }}
```

Test case

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var request = require("request");
var PlanMgmnt = require('../routes/PlanManagement/PlanManagement')();

describe("--Plan Management API", function () {
describe("--Add Plan API", function () {
    it("--returns status 200", function (done) {
        PlanMgmnt.getPlansList({}, function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
        // done();
    });
});});
```

It not printing the **res** in console.log.

Comment: have you stubbed `plan_details.find()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, the issue was due to the MongoDB connection, unit test cases do not get the MongoDB connection there for unit test cases were failing to execute the mongoose function.

To fix the problem, added helper.js file, added the mongoose connection code in this file, used the helper.js file in test command
"test": "mocha test --require helper.js".

OR also cam use the mongo-unit package.

Refs:https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/integration-and-e2e-tests-nodejs-mongodb

Answer (score -1):

The `done()` should be put inside as below:

```
describe("--Add Plan API", function () {
    it("--returns status 200", function (done) {
        PlanMgmnt.getPlansList({}, function(res){
            console.log(res);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

> you can set the timeout for each suite or each test

```
describe('suite descripion', function(){
  this.timeout(15000);

it('test description', function(done){
  this.timeout(15000);
});
});
```

Comment: Timeout is not a proper solution, we can't ensure that test cases ran properly or not.